# how to see result directly after change some property without re-run the code Flet-Pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, flet

I'm try to make simple app with Flet in PyCharm, My problem is when I change simple properties ( Code ) for example change bgcolor I have to re-run code to se result, there is Any way to see result directly ( live update ) without re-run code in PyCharm?

Answer (score 1):

For Hot reload Just in terminal write **flet -r filename.py** then when chage code just save ( ctrl+s ) it will updating